# clang/gcc profile instrumentation options

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, profiler

I want to write a library (C++) for profiling an executable file at runtime, for example tracing a call stack. I found the **-finstrument-functions** option for *gcc/clang* compilers and I know how to use it. I also found other options such as **-fprofile-generate, -fprofile-use, -fprofile-arcs, -fprofile-instr-generate** and others. I have read the reference to the *clang/gcc* options, but I don't understand what I can use these options for. What is the purpose of these options and how to work with them?
Thank you.

Comment: Try also using these instrumentation options with `gcc -fverbose -O -S` and look inside the generated assembler code

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch i don't know about option **-fverbose** and can't find it on gcc man page. You talk about **-fverbose-asm**?

Comment: Yes, sorry for the typo, meant `gcc -O -fverbose-asm -S`